# Larger number of filters performs worse than smaller number in conv2D layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a bunch of 2D images, and I am performing convolution on them. I am experimenting with with the number of filters in the convolutional layer, and I have found that the training worsens when increase the filters. For example, my setup looks likes this:

1. Conv2D(**8**, (3,3), input_shape = (100, 100, 1)),
2. Flatten()
3. Dense(Output)

And for this, let's say training RMSE is 0.245. But, if I change Conv2D(**16**, (3,3), input_shape = (100, 100, 1)), the training RMSE gets worse, and gets to 0.534, for example. Please note that I am keeping same random_seed why running my experiment.

Can somebody explain why this could be happening? I kinda thought that if I increase the number of channels, the model will have less struggle to learn the data, and thus predict better too.

Thank you!

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing about dataset, your full model.

Comment: Kindly share the dataset statistics along with model summary.

Comment: Thanks for responding to the issue. The nature of the input is 2D landscape images in black and white. After investigating the issue, I have found that the batchNorm layer i had right after the first conv layer caused the issues in the first place. Therefore, removing helped elevate the problem.